# Accessing key of a dictionary in R

Tags: r

I created a dictionary like this

```
dict = new.env()
key <- "test"
dict$key <- 20
```

But when I want to key of the dictionary, I do this

```
print(ls(dict))
```

but what is returned is "key" and not "test".

I tried doing this as well

```
dict[["key"]] <- 20
```

but I get the same results. So how can I access the keys of my dictionary?

Comment: `key` is not showing up in an environment that you did not put it in. Try `print(key)` to see that `"test"` is still there.

Comment: indeed it is the actual key. Please excuse my ignorance, how do I put it? Is it not dict$key<-value or dict[["key"]]????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either environments or lists as dictionaries (personally, I prefer the latter), in this way:

```
### using environment as dictionary
dict <- new.env()
dict[["key 1"]] <- 20
dict[["key 2"]] <- "ABC"

# let's see the keys:
ls(envir = dict)
# access by name:
dict[["key 1"]]
dict[["key 2"]]


### using list as dictionary
dict <- list()
dict[["key 1"]] <- 20
dict[["key 2"]] <- "ABC"

# let's see the keys:
names(dict)
# access by name:
dict[["key 1"]]
dict[["key 2"]]

# of course, in both case you can use a character variable to define the key,  e.g. :
myKey <- "key 3"
dict[[myKey]] <- 123
print(dict[[myKey]])
# > [1] 123
```

Comment: But now do I iterates through it like a list if I used the second case? I mean iterating through all the key

Comment: I don't know exactly what you need but for example you can iterate all the values using a loop `for(n in names(dict)) print(dict[[n]])`,

Answer (score 1):

I would create a dictionary like this:

```
> dict<-c(1:20)
> names(dict)<-letters[1:20]
> dict
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
> dict["t"]
 t 
20
```